# Advised equipment to make a vlog

Tags: tips-and-tricks, electronic-items

Our daughter is going to undertake a 3 month trip to Ethiopia as part of her school education to help start-up a school project there. In her spare time, she would like to visit the surroundings and **keep some kind of a video diary**. Something worth watching years later.

- Can anyone share some experience about what video equipment worked for them. No Internet access required imo.
- Is something like a GoPro recommended or did a small camera worked best for you?
- What where your considerations when deciding between a GoPro or a small camera?
- I only know about GoPro and/or small camera but perhaps there's something easier?

I'm no traveler by any means but *I would expect* following to be important

- Battery life
- Recording time
- Robustness
- Weight
- Ease of use
- and off course video quality

**Edit**

I have massaged the question a bit trying to clear up some of the confusion. If this is still a better fit for another site *(like https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)*, I'll repost there but the question is as much about the material used as about soliciting some first hand experience while traveling.

Comment: This might (I don't fully understand what's on topic there) be a better question for [hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question about video equipment, not travel

Comment: @CMaster What might be on topic is internet access in Ethiopia.

Comment: Also, what camera are you thinking of that is **smaller** than a GoPro? (I know they exist, but they tend to be toys, not actually useful for anything)

Comment: It is not the camera, it is the person behind it. Vlogs can be made with a moderate smart phone, with the selfie camera, as long as the person presenting has good things to say.

Comment: I do think i'd lean towards a phone or tablet with a good camera over a seperate recording and editing/uploading device.

Comment: Bad audio can be quite harmful. You might want to look at vbloggers (not necessarily travel ones) and see what they are using. For [example](https://usesthis.com/interviews/dave.jones/)

Comment: I do feel that this could be turned into a decent travel question with the some appropriate massaging of the text.

Comment: @CMaster - it's indeed about video equipment, not travel but I did not now where to ask and assumed that other travelers must have faced the same question and had some experience to share. I've been told that a GoPro is good to capture action scene's but if you wan't to film the surroundings, a camera would be more appropriate. Both have there pro's and cons and before buying either one, I thought I better asked.